# Sorting IP addresses with different formats

Tags: python, sorting

I am trying to get:

```
['192.168.70.19 (tcp/1433)']
['192.168.70.223 (tcp/1051),192.168.70.19 (tcp/1025), 192.168.70.245 (tcp/1051)'] 
['192.168.70.19 (tcp/3389),192.168.70.223 (tcp/3389)']
```

to

```
['192.168.70.19 (tcp/1433)']
['192.168.70.19 (tcp/1025),192.168.70.223 (tcp/1051), 192.168.70.245 (tcp/1051)'] 
['192.168.70.19 (tcp/3389),192.168.70.223 (tcp/3389)']
```

This is my code, it is not right. I am having trouble sorting the IP address due to the wanting to retain the tcp part. Does anyone have a better suggestion or solution to this. Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
import re
a=['192.168.70.19 (tcp/1433)', '192.168.70.223 (tcp/1051),192.168.70.19 (tcp/1025),192.168.70.245 (tcp/1025)', '192.168.70.19 (tcp/3389),192.168.70.223 (tcp/3389)']


for z in a:
    if z.find(','):
        #removes tcp part (but I want to keep)        
        #b = re.sub(r'\(.*?\)', '', z)

        #I can sort the IP with this, but it doesnt have the tcp part.
        #z.sort(key=lambda s: map(int, s.split('(')[0].split('.')))
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the following list comprehension:

```
[','.join(sorted(i.split(','), key=lambda s: tuple(map(int, s.split()[0].split('.'))))) for i in a]
```

so that with the following input (note that I've changed the `192.168.70.19` in your sample input to `192.168.70.39` to demonstrate that the IP-addresses are sorted numerically):

```
a=['192.168.70.19 (tcp/1433)',
   '192.168.70.223 (tcp/1051),192.168.70.39 (tcp/1025),192.168.70.245 (tcp/1025)',
   '192.168.70.19 (tcp/3389),192.168.70.223 (tcp/3389)']
```

the above list comprehension would return:

```
['192.168.70.19 (tcp/1433)',
 '192.168.70.39 (tcp/1025),192.168.70.223 (tcp/1051),192.168.70.245 (tcp/1025)', 
 '192.168.70.19 (tcp/3389),192.168.70.223 (tcp/3389)']`
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution without regex

```
[','.join(sorted(x.split(','), key= lambda x: x.split()[0])) for x in a]
```

To sort the IP+TCP combination, use first part of that tuple to sort on ip addr

output:

```
['192.168.70.19 (tcp/1433)', 
'192.168.70.19 (tcp/1025),192.168.70.223 (tcp/1051),192.168.70.245 (tcp/1025)', 
'192.168.70.19 (tcp/3389),192.168.70.223 (tcp/3389)']
```

Comment: This incorrectly sorts the IP-address lexicographically rather than numerically, so `192.168.70.123` would be ahead of `192.168.70.20`, for example.